# Retrieve title-attribute of hyperlink in JEditorPane on mouse hover

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, mouselistener, jeditorpane

I want to add tooltips to hyperlinks in a (non-editable) `JEditorPane`. I found some hints on the web, but none of them worked for me. This is my current approach:

```
jEditorPaneIsFollower.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener() {
    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int pos = jEditorPaneIsFollower.viewToModel(evt.getPoint());
        if (pos >= 0) {
            HTMLDocument hdoc = (HTMLDocument)jEditorPaneIsFollower.getDocument();
            javax.swing.text.Element e = hdoc.getCharacterElement(pos);
            AttributeSet a = e.getAttributes();
            String href = (String) a.getAttribute(javax.swing.text.html.HTML.Attribute.TITLE);
            if (href != null) {
                jEditorPaneIsFollower.setToolTipText(href);
            } else {
                jEditorPaneIsFollower.setToolTipText(null);
            }
        }
        else {
            jEditorPaneIsFollower.setToolTipText(null);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        //
    }
});
```

The initialization of my editor pane:

```
jEditorPaneIsFollower.setEditable(false);
jEditorPaneIsFollower.setContentType("text/html");
jEditorPaneIsFollower.setDocument(new HTMLDocument());
jEditorPaneIsFollower.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
```

The content of the editor pane is following:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="1%" valign="top">
          &#220;bergeordnet:
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
          <a href="#cr_288" alt="DRGs als Prozesssteuerung" title="DRGs als Prozesssteuerung">288</a> 
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

From debugging, I see that `pos` always changes when I move the mouse over the editor pane, however, the character element `e` is always `null`.

So my questions are:

1. Do I need to set editor kit and document type to HTML when initializing the editor pane?
2. How can I fetch the right element and access the title attribute to set it as tooltip when moving the mouse over the editor pane?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be dealing with the wrong elements, `HTML.Attribute.TITLE` is neither a anchor tag or property of an anchor tag...

Instead, you need to extract the `HTML.Tag.A` attribute from the document `Element`, you then need to extract the `HTML.Attribute.HREF` from it...

Instead of using a `MouseListener`, you could override the components `getToolTipText` method which is called by the `ToolTipManager` and would allow you to customise the value returned, for example...

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane() {

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent evt) {
        String text = null;
        int pos = viewToModel(evt.getPoint());
        if (pos >= 0) {
            HTMLDocument hdoc = (HTMLDocument) getDocument();
            javax.swing.text.Element e = hdoc.getCharacterElement(pos);
            AttributeSet a = e.getAttributes();

            SimpleAttributeSet value = (SimpleAttributeSet) a.getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A);
            if (value != null) {
                String href = (String) value.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.HREF);
                if (href != null) {
                    text = href;
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }

};
```

Using this would require you to manually register the component with the `ToolTipManager`, as `setToolTipText` does this normally...

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(editorPane);
```

nb: If you want to display the `alt` value, you should use `HTML.Attribute.TITLE` instead of `HTML.Attribute.HREF`

Comment: HTML.Tag.A is not the only tag that can have the `HREF` attribute. It can also be in `base`, `link`, and `area`. Of these, `area` is clickable too.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use a `HyperlinkListener`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public final class HyperlinkTooltipTest {
  private static final String HTML_TEXT = "<html><body>"
    + "<table><tr>"
    + "<td width=\"1%\" valign=\"top\">"
    + "&#220;bergeordnet:"
    + "</td>"
    + "<td valign=\"top\">"
    + "<a href=\"#cr_288\" alt=\"DRGs als Prozesssteuerung\" title=\"DRGs als Prozesssteuerung\">288</a>"
    + "</td></tr></table>"
    + "</body></html>";

  private JComponent makeUI() {
    JEditorPane jEditorPaneIsFollower = new JEditorPane();
    jEditorPaneIsFollower.setEditable(false);
    jEditorPaneIsFollower.setContentType("text/html");
    jEditorPaneIsFollower.setDocument(new HTMLDocument());
    jEditorPaneIsFollower.setEditorKit(new HTMLEditorKit());
    jEditorPaneIsFollower.setText(HTML_TEXT);
    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().registerComponent(jEditorPaneIsFollower);

    jEditorPaneIsFollower.addHyperlinkListener(new HyperlinkListener() {
      private String tooltip;
      @Override public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
        JEditorPane editor = (JEditorPane) e.getSource();
        if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED) {
          System.out.println(e);
        } else if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ENTERED) {
          tooltip = editor.getToolTipText();
          Element elem = e.getSourceElement();
          if (elem != null) {
            AttributeSet attr = elem.getAttributes();
            AttributeSet a = (AttributeSet) attr.getAttribute(HTML.Tag.A);
            if (a != null) {
              editor.setToolTipText((String) a.getAttribute(HTML.Attribute.TITLE));
            }
          }
        } else if (e.getEventType() == HyperlinkEvent.EventType.EXITED) {
          editor.setToolTipText(tooltip);
        }
      }
    });
    return new JScrollPane(jEditorPaneIsFollower);
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(new HyperlinkTooltipTest().makeUI());
    f.setSize(320, 240);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomEditorPane:

```
@Override
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent _event) {
    int pos_ = viewToModel(_event.getPoint());
    if (pos_ < 0) {
        //If not found, then return null
        return null;
    }
    HTMLDocument hdoc_ = (HTMLDocument) getDocument();
    Element e_ = hdoc_.getCharacterElement(pos_);
    AttributeSet a_ = e_.getAttributes();

    Enumeration<?> enumm_ = a_.getAttributeNames();
    while (enumm_.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object o_ = enumm_.nextElement();
        if (!o_.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            //skip html tags that are not anchors
            continue;
        }
        Object value_ = a_.getAttribute(o_);
        //Test if the anchor has an attribute "title"
        if (!(value_ instanceof SimpleAttributeSet)) {
            continue;
        }
        SimpleAttributeSet attSet_ = (SimpleAttributeSet)value_;
        Enumeration<?> at_ = attSet_.getAttributeNames();
        while (at_.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object att_ = at_.nextElement();
            if (att_.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                //return the value of the title of the anchor
                return attSet_.getAttribute(att_).toString();
            }
            //skip other attributes of this anchor
        }
    }
    //The visited tag is not an anchor or the visited anchor has no attribute named title
    return null;
}
```